# Google Maps pushing content down?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, layout

I have two columns, contact information on the left and a google map on the right. However the Google Map is pushing all of the content in the left column now when I don't want it to. It's probably something simple but I can't seem to get it working. I understand that the google map won't work without the API key, but I have already requested one and that is not needed anyway, as the content is still pushed down on the left column. The columns stack when the screen is at mobile size and that works correctly, it's just for desktop screens where the two columns are shown side by side. Thank you for your help!

Comment: `vertical-align: top;` on your `table-cell`

Comment: Of course, I completely forgot about vertical align. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.leftColumn {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Will align your left column content back to the top. With elements that sit next to each other, it's often a headache saver to include the `vertical-align` property.

Comment: Of course, I completely forgot about vertical align. Thank you!